# Python Class Quest

Tags: python

Hey guys i have a python Question The Problem says Define the method object inc_num_kids() for PersonInfo. inc_num_kids increments the member data num_kids. Sample output for the given program:
Kids: 0
New baby, kids now: 1

```
class PersonInfo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num_kids = 0

# FIXME: Write inc_num_kids(self)
def inc_num_kids(self,num):
    num=1
    self.num_kids+=num

person1 = PersonInfo()

print('Kids:', person1.num_kids)
person1.inc_num_kids()
print('New baby, kids now:', person1.num_kids)
```

I Have already tried writeing the method myself and i got an error saying personinfo has no attribute inc_num_kids what should i do?

Comment: First thing is to fix the indentation of your inc_num_kids (as this could be the answer to your question).

Comment: Also, you _need_ to give `inc_num_kids` the exact function signature shown in the FIXME comment.

Comment: I tried that and it still not wworking.

Answer (score 3):

You need to indent `inc_num_kids` into the `PersonInfo` class. Currently it is just a standalone function. Python is sensitive to indentation and scoping is done by level of indentation:

```
class PersonInfo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num_kids = 0

    def inc_num_kids(self, num=1):
        self.num_kids += num
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class PersonInfo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num_kids = 0
    def inc_num_kids(self, num=1):
        self.num_kids += num

person1 = PersonInfo()

print('Kids:', person1.num_kids)
person1.inc_num_kids()
print('New baby, kids now:', person1.num_kids)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).